# React native generate ProGuard mapping files

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I am running crash reporting with firebase and would really like to see the error stack trace.

I get the message:

```
Upload a ProGuard mapping file to deobfuscate future stack traces for version X
```

I am just not sure how to generate the file from react-native.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly generate a release build using `./gradlew assembleRelease` or `./gradlew assembleBundle` from inside the android directory.

If ProGuard is enabled, a mapping.txt file will be generated in `/android/app/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt`.

Uploading this file to Google Play will allow you to deobfuscate stack traces.